# When to load data in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I come from writing SPA in angular which is quite an opinated framework

I’m trying to work out which concept for loading async data is best

In angular I’d normally have page components inject a service and that service is responsible for loading data and then the page is then responsible for passing that data down to the dumb display components.

The other approach is to use configuration in the router. So it finishing all promises before allowing the user to navigate to the view

Which patterns fit blazor for data loading?

I know services are equivalent to injected classes which are registered as singletons.

I just don’t know which is the best pattern for data loading. I don’t want to load everything up front since different urls require different api calls and thus I’ll be loading data that user may never actually need.

Comment: There are a couple of answers below so I'll not repeat what they have already said.  There are many articles and demos on the Internet of ways to structure your application.  I personally use a "Clean Design" approach.  Just search "Blazor Clean Design" for resources.  To answer your statement "I don't want to load everything up front".  Blazor doesn't.  It only loads DI services as they are used.  And clears them based on their scope.  You choose their Scope, based on your design.  And don't  ignore the `OwningComponentBase` component.

Answer (score 1):

The basic pattern looks like:

```
@inject ItemService ItemService

@*  use items *@

@code
{
  private List<Item> Items = new();

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
     items = await ItemService.Get();
  }
}
```

> I know services are equivalent to injected classes which are registered as singletons.

Yes they are the same but do not use Singleton for normal services. In Blazor Wasm AddTransient() is the norm. Only use Singleton for Application wide state management.

> I don’t want to load everything up front

then delay the loading until the right condition has been set.